# How to use a model as a queue in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to keep track of the last requested articles in a 'Last Seen' list. 
I have RecentVisits model to do so:

```
class RecentVisit(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default='', blank='false', max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(default='', blank='false', max_length=100)
```

I want to keep the model as  a fixed width queue (FILA), so I'm wondering what's the best way to do so? By `best`, I mean the solution that does require the least database hits.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the solution that I've came up with:

```
    l = RecentVisit.objects.values()            
    lastest_requests = l[::-1]

    #Keep database table size constant by throwing away last element 
    if len(lastest_requests) > N_SAVED_ALLOWED:
        lastest_requests.pop()
    #Empty table     
    RecentVisit.objects.all().delete()

    #Check of duplicates before saving to db
    if not any(d['title'] == post.title for d in lastest_requests):
        new_visit = RecentVisit(title= post.title, slug= post.slug) 
        new_visit.save()            
    #refill table with remaining (N-1) values    
    for r in lastest_requests:
        req = RecentVisit(title= r['title'], slug= r['slug'])             
        req.save()
```

I adds about 30ms overhead on my development environment. However I'm not sure it is the most economic one, so still looking for better solutions.

Comment: Have you looked at this -> [django-visits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-visits/0.1.6)

Comment: Yes, but that's a hit counter too and overkill for my simple use case.

Comment: how would you like a solution that doesn't make any database hits at all?

Comment: @e4c5 Please read carefully. I need `least database hits`.

Comment: So i thought you would jump at a solution that wouldn't involve any at all?